# How to model/get a capacitor to discharge slowly at first?

Tags: capacitor, waveform, capacitor-charging

Typically, a capacitor discharges fast at first, and then discharging slows down until it approaches 0. Is there a way to slow the initial phase of discharging, so the capacitor does not immediately discharge so quickly? It should start discharging slowly, speed up, and slow down again.

My goal is NOT to generally slow down discharging - I would like to change just the "shape" of the curve describing its discharging. Ideally, the resulting shape would resemble an S-shaped or logistic curve (in reverse, since it goes from high to low).

Comment: Temporarily increase the impedance it is discharging into.

Comment: Add an inductor in series with the resistor.

Comment: Potential XY problem.

Comment: How about a voltage controlled current sink (there’s a classical op amp circuit for that), with a DAC that generates a variable voltage to control the current drawn? Recall that the derivative of the capacitor voltage is a function of itscharge/discharge current.

Comment: Use a thermistor?

Answer (score 2):

An inductor limits the rate of change of current though it (by an amount depending on the voltage across the inductor and the reciprocal of its inductance).  So an inductor in series with the capacitor, and perhaps in parallel with a diode if you want to control the discharge only (and not the charge up), will slow down the early discharge rate of a capacitor.  A bigger inductor will slow down the rate more.

Comment: Yes, easiest way to do it!